# What does it mean to reference a function (e.g., in Javascript)?

Tags: javascript

In Head First Ajax, they give the following example:

```
function getDetails(itemName) {
  request = createRequest();
  if (request == null) {
    alert("Unable to create request");
    return;
  }
  var url= "getDetails.php?ImageID=" + escape(itemName);
  request.open("GET", url, true);
  request.onreadystatechange = displayDetails;//This references the function below
  request.send(null);
}

function displayDetails() {
  if (request.readyState == 4) {
    if (request.status == 200) {
      detailDiv = document.getElementById("description");
      detailDiv.innerHTML = request.responseText;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm curious what kind of construction is `request.onreadystatechange = displayDetails;`.  The book says that "this is a reference to a function, not a function call".  However I don't understand what this **really** means.  I suppose it assigns the `displayDetails` function to the object `request.onreadystatechange`, but I don't understand why or when to use this construction.

For example, what is the advantage of using this construction rather than doing something like:

```
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (request.readyState == 4) {
    if (request.status == 200) {
      detailDiv = document.getElementById("description");
      detailDiv.innerHTML = request.responseText;
    }
  }
}
```

Also, is that an example of a functional language feature?

Comment: Honestly, the first code block posted is sloppy as it pollutes the global scope. The reason to use a named function for a callback, is in the cases where you'd also need to call that function explicitly elsewhere.

Comment: The title of the question says Javascript but in the question you say 'Head First Java'.  The code looks like Javascript, not Java.  Is that correct?

Comment: IMO it keeps things clean. Though as the person above me says that the example is a little sloppy. Also did you know that when you write something like `request.onreadystatechange = function () { ... }` you are actually assigning the _reference_ of an `anonymous` javascript function?

Comment: @Shmiddty not sure that it's still a problem, but named functions used to provide more readable stacktraces

Comment: @soulcheck You could also make a *named* function expression, such as `request.onreadystatechange = function displayDetails() { ... }`. [There are some problems with it](http://kiro.me/blog/nfe_dilemma.html), but you'll get readable stack traces without polluting the global scope.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens ahh, I often get function expressions and definition mixed up

Comment: @soulcheck Admitted, that construct is *nearly identical* to a nested function definition: `function getDetails(itemName) { /* code */ function displayDetails() { /* code */ } }`. However, the named function expression has the advantage that it can be defined where it is actually used.

Comment: @shargors - it's javascript, I'm correcting my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's an example of a functional language feature. Functions are first-class citizens on those languages, meaning they can also be passed around, assigned to variables, etc.

About your question on `eventhandler = function () { }` versus `eventhandler = somefunc`, you said:

> I suppose it assigns the `displayDetails` function to the object `request.onreadystatechange`, but I don't understand why or when to use this construction

The `request` object has a property called `onreadystatechange`, which represents an event handler function that should be called when the request's `readyState` property changes. That's why the book said it's not a function call, but a reference assignment. You're not calling the function when you assign it to `request.onreadystatechange`, it will be called only when that event happens. Clicks and all other events work like that (they're basically *asynchronous*).

It makes sense to use a function reference instead of an anonymous function assigment if you want to use the same handler for more than one event. For example, if you have two "save" buttons on two different parts of a web page, you can assign the same handler function to their click events.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm curious what kind of construction is request.onreadystatechange = displayDetails;. The book says that "this is a reference to a function, not a function call". However I don't understand what this really means.

Essentially this means that your assigning a pre-defined, named function as the event handler for the particular event (in this case readystatechange).

You could also assign an anonymous function depending on your needs:

```
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        if (request.status == 200) {
            detailDiv = document.getElementById("description");
            detailDiv.innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared a function called `displayDetails`. If you ignore the `function` syntax for a moment, what' you're actually doing is creating an object, almost like `var displayDetails = something`. When you are assigning the `onreadystatechange` you are actually assigning a function to it, not a *call to* the function. This means `request.onreadystatechange` and `function displayDetails()...` are the same *reference*. Calling `request.onreadystate()` is the same as calling `displayDetails()`.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage is that you can use `displayDetails` elsewhere, for example as a `onreadystatechange` callback for another AJAX request.

If there's only one place where this specific callback is used (which is often the case), it's probably more clear to use an anonymous function expression. That way, you keep the creation and the handling of the request in the same place.

On another note, if the `displayDetails` function is not nested in another function's scope (such as `(function() { ... })()`, it will pollute the global scope.

Comment: What does it mean to "pollute the global scope"?

Comment: When you create a lot of global variables (or functions) with fairly common names, it becomes more likely that one of those will collide with a name from another script, plugin or library. It is considered a good practice to keep local variables and functions out of the global scope (i.e. inside a function scope) and only expose the variables and functions which need to be accessible from the outside. Even then, you can reduce pollution by keeping all of your exported stuff in one namespace, e.g. `myplugin.coolFunction()` instead of just `coolFunction()`.

Answer (score 1):

> I suppose it assigns the displayDetails function to the object request.onreadystatechange

Precisely. Functions are first class variables in Javascript and can be passed around and stored in variables, just like objects and numbers. In fact, functions don't really have names and when you access them you are just accessing them via a variable. That is, something like

```
function f() { }
```

Is actually kind of syntax sugar for

```
var f = function(){ }
```

> but I don't understand why or when to use this construction.

Functions serve the same sort of roles as objects (in the object-orientation sense), specially if you close them over some internal state. In cases in an OO language where you would pass something an object with a single `doStuff` or `call` method you could instead pass a function instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your two code examples are equivalent in the terms you are using. A function is sitting somewhere in memory. If we take a reference to that memory location (that address) and store it somewhere, we can run that function from that stored reference. (Note that in Javascript this explanation is more of an analogy that what is really happening. In some languages, its the way it really works.)

In the first bit of code, the reference to the function is stored in something named "displayDetails". That's the global scope variable that is a possible coding issue. But it is valid. Note also that that reference gets copied into "request.onreadystatechange" as well.

In the second bit of code, the reference to the function is stored in "request.onreadystatechange"

Either way, the function gets run when the request is being processed to check whether the result has come back or not.